# Bacula - Understand a schedule

Tags: schedule, backup-strategies, bacula

I'm studying bacula and I need to understand this schedule:

```
Schedule {
   Name = Daily
   Run  = Full 1st sun at 00:05
   Run  = Differential 2nd-5th sun at 00:05
   Run  = Incremental mon-sat at 00:05
}
```

And this is what I understand:

1. There's a full backup every first Sunday of the month at 00:05
2. There's a differential backup every Sunday of second, third, fourth, and fifth week of the month at 00:05
3. There'a an incremental backup every day from Monday to Friday at 00:05

Is that correct?

In 2. the differential backup refers to the previous full/differential backup? So to the previous Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are correct.

in 3.There is an incremental backup every day from Monday to Saturday at 00:05

Now differential backups refer to the previous **full backup**. So it will refer to one to 3 Sundays ago.

This way in order to restore a file, Bacula needs to go back and look for

- one full backup
- one differential backup
- some incremental backups

[image: bacula restore policy]